# How to account for varying doses within a data set?

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset: [image]

These patients got multiple prescriptions during a period of time. I am looking at 98 days window. I initially wanted to see which days within the 98-day period the patient uses a medication and wanted to take care of overlapping periods by shifting them to the day after the end of prescription 1 (filled_dt) in case prescription 1 and prescription 2 overlap. I created 98 indicator variables with values of 1 in case the filled_dt and days supply cover the 98-day period (and which ones exactly). This is my code:

```
data pdc;
set shoe;
array daydummy(98) day1-day98;
array filldates(*) fill_dt1 - fill_dt5;
array days_supply(*) days_supply1-days_supply5;
do ii=1 to 98; daydummy(ii)=0;end;
do ii=1 to 98;
    do i = 1 to dim(filldates) while (filldates(i) ne .);
        if filldates(i)<= start_dt + ii -1 <= filldates(i)+days_supply(i)-1
        then daydummy(ii)=1;
    end;
    do u=2 to 5 while (filldates(u) ne .);
        if filldates(u)<filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1)
        then filldates(u)=filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1);
    end;
end;
drop i ii;
dayscovered=sum(of day1 - day98);label dayscovered='Total Days Covered';
p_dayscovered=dayscovered/98;label p_dayscovered='Proportion of Days Covered';
run;
```

The second "do" takes care of crediting the overlaps. I am basically following this paper code: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/forum2007/043-2007.pdf
However, I have an added complexity:
Each week is associated with an average daily dose. How do I multiply my indicator weeks (day1-day98) with the average daily dose associated with each filled prescription. I also need to keep taking into account the shift once two prescriptions overlap, as well as days covered and percentage of days covered.